# About the setting of virtual os under Azure platform

Tags: azure

I have a project run on Azure platform and I have set up all the configurations, most important of all, the database. But the tricky thing is that I login into the virtual machine several days later, all the settings are disappeared. What's the matter? I haven't done anything to the VM..
Can anyone help?

Comment: What settings are you talking about?  Your Service Configuration, Web.config, etc.

Comment: According to my project, I designed several specific tables on the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be that you changed these settings in a Web Role / Worker Role (PaaS)? You have to know that these 'virtual machines' are not persistent. These virtual machines are provisioned with a package you upload through the portal or Visual Studio for example. Every change you make through remote desktop that wasn't included in the package (installing a database for example), will get lost whenever a hardware failure occurs, when your instance gets a Windows Update, ...

If you want to keep those changes you have 2 options:

1. Script the changes with a [Startup Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg456327.aspx) and include the script in the service package. The startup tasks will always be executed when your instance is created or whenever it gets replaced by a new instance (in case of a hardware failure).
2. Don't use PaaS but use IaaS instead. This is the [Virtual Machines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj156003.aspx) preview feature. With Virtual Machines, you can connect to your VM through remote desktop to install and configure whatever you like. The system disks and additional data disks are persisted to blob storage, so you won't loose any of your changes.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your problem description and comment **"I haven't changed anything. they're just gone.... I have to set up them again."** you may have setup configuration incorrectly either by log into the VM using RD or something done locally later once application was running via application interface. And in both cases the setting will not persist when VM is recycled due to any planned or unplanned reason.

So the key here is how to correctly configure the setting with your application so the settings will persist. If you will try following same method it will not persist again and cause same problem. Depend on what kind of application configuration you may need, i.e. [SQL database connection configuration during application development](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/tutorials/cloud-service-with-sql-database/) or using [Startup task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg456327.aspx) will help you to create settings which will persist during VM recycle.